# nextJS how to load an environment variable properly

Tags: next.js, dotenv

I am used to React and recently moved to NextJs, but facing a weird scenario.
Having this Demo component rendered in a demo page;

```
import React from 'react';

import { Hello, Header } from './demo.styled';

export const Demo = () => {

  const name = process.env.userName || 'world';
  console.log("env vars userName v2: ", name)
  // env vars userName v2:  John Doe

  return (
    <Header>
      <Hello>Hello {name}!</Hello>
    </Header>
  );
};
```

I am having a .env file where the userName is John Doe, as you can see below the console log is the output, and it is well loaded.

But when my page is loaded, I get.

> Hello world!

My project is recent, I am using

> "next": "^12.1.4", "react": "17", "react-dom": "17",

And, my page is very simplistic, all it does is render the demo component.

### Update

> The logs set above are in server side, but in the client side, I have
> this message: next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Text content did not match.
> Server: "Jhon Doe" Client: "world"

What I understand is that my .env file is only on the server side, So how could I have these information on the client side too.

Comment: Where did you define `process.env.userName` value?

Comment: in a .env file at the root of the project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this document](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

> By default environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.

As for your case, `process.env.userName` is only compiled during build-time and is available on the server-side merely.

If you want to have it on the client-side, you need to have the prefix for your config `NEXT_PUBLIC_userName` (but following the name convention, I'd suggest you modify it to `NEXT_PUBLIC_USERNAME`)

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_USERNAME=Jhon Doe
```

And then you can change your code to

```
const name = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USERNAME || 'world';
```

If you want to expose that `userName` on the client-side explicitly. You can update your `next.config.js` like below

Your original env

```
userName=Jhon Doe
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  //add other configs here too
  env: {
    userName: process.env.userName,
  },
}
```

With the 2nd solution, you don't need to modify your environment variables.

Comment: Restart the server after the change.